# WPF MVVM Master detail view with a datagrid and a TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am trying to implement a Master detail view in WPF MVVM.

In my viewmodel I have a observable collection of "Causes". Each Cause has an observable collection of "Solutions".

I bound an editable Datagrid to the Causes and it is working fine. But when a user selects a row in the DataGrid I want to allow the user to see its associated solutions in the TabControl.

How should I go about doing this? Should I create a property CurrentCause in the Viewmodel and bind it to the SelectedItem. In the TabControl can I bind to CurrentCause.Solutions.

Will this be an optimal approach? Please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the `ItemsSource` of the TabControl to be the `SelectedItem` of the DataGrid using element binding.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Solutions}">
```

Comment: Really? is it possible to bind DataContext to another control as well? Should I use DataContext = {Binding Path=CauseControlName.SelectedItem}?

Comment: Yes you can bind the DataContext, but if you want to display each Solution as a tab, then you'll need to bind the ItemsSource

Comment: It doesnt work :( My TabConrol comes as completely blank. I tried both x:Name and Name in the Master datagrid

Comment: I tried this syntax as well - ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CauseDataGrid} But it still comes as blank... :'(

Comment: I've just tried this and it works, do your Cause and Solution types implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Are you using properties and not public fields?

Comment: It is working now. I did a stupid mistake of only initializing the Observable Collection in the Property but not add an empty object in the collection for the controls to be rendered. Your method works perfectly. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to True and do something like [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/11/08/three-levels-master-detail-with-wpf/).

Comment: I tried to set the DataContext of the parent stack panel                         <StackPanel.DataContext>
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Causes}" />
                        </StackPanel.DataContext> 

But it doesnt work.

Comment: problem is solved now with Dev's method of binding the TabControl's ItemSource to the selected Item of the DataGrid. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would bind your DataGrid to a list of Causes, the SelectedItem to CurrentCause in your Model and the TabControl to Solutions. Then you have everything nicely tied up in your MVVM.

```
private Cause _currentCause;
public Cause CurrentCause
{
    get { return _currentCause; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentCause == value) return;
            CurrentSolution = _currentCause.Solutions;  //However you do this...
        _currentCause = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentCause");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Cause> _causes;
public ObservableCollection<Cause> Causes
{
    get { return _causes; }
    set
    {
        _causes = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Causes");
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<Solution> _solutions;
public ObservableCollection<Solution> Solutions
{
    get { return _solutions; }
    set
    {
        _solutions = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Companies");
    }
}



<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Causes}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCause}"...
```

Comment: thanks but i was able to achieve this without the extra property. But I might need to for some other issue :(